# iOS Swift - Add target(selector) to string

Tags: ios, string, swift, target, hashtag

Is there a way to add a target to a specified word from an UITextView? For example. 
I want to add a target to a hash-tagged word from a UITextView.
I'm using a function to get an array with the hash-tagged words from the textview, but I don't know how to add them a target, or a tap-gesture.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an attributed string to set the text in the text view. That attributed string uses link attributes (`NSLinkAttributeName` with a URL value of your choice) in the range of your target hash-tagged words. You need to search the text for your hash-tagged words and add the appropriate link attributes. You probably want to create the link URLs to have a custom scheme and include information about the hash-tagged word. When one of the links is tapped you get a delegate callback from the text view.

Comment: I want to perform a segue after tapped that word. I've already created a function that search the text for hash-tagged words and set change their color.

Comment: Ok, so modify that to set link attributes and then trigger the segue in the delegate callback

Comment: string.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "segue1", range: range)
How can I get the callback ?

Comment: Add a delegate to the view and check the delegate methods, I don't recall the name of hand, something about url handling

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question recently and I found a solution that fit my needs. It's not perfect but maybe it will help:

I decided to go for a whole text button with specific style around my target element. In a user experience way, user may be inclined to touch the styled word.

```
@IBOutlet weak var stringBtn: UIButton!
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        let string = "string with #tag" as NSString
        var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string as String)
        let firstAttributes = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: 1, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

        attributedString.addAttributes(firstAttributes, range: string.rangeOfString("#tag"))

        stringBtn.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, forState: .Normal)

        //Add target to your button
    }
```